# Indexing a Numpy Array (4 dimensions)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix, indexing

I have a numpy array which is (1, 2048, 1, 1). I need to assign the first two dimensions to another numpy array which is (1, 2048), but I am confused on how to index it correctly. Hope you can help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by using np.squeeze(x) to remove the singleton dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

In this specific case where the last two dimensions are 1,1 you can also use `reshape`.

```
b = a.reshape((1,2048))
```